# Format created_at datetime using Carbon and display result in laravel blade

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I'm trying to display `created_at` datetime into like `a minute ago` using `Carbon` inside my laravel blade file. I use `vue.js` to display the data but not working.

**Controller:**

```
public function data()
    {
        $projects = Project::get();
        return [
            'created' => $projects->created_at->diffForHumans()
        ];
        return \Response::json($projects);
    }
```

**Blade with vue:**

```
<tr v-for="Project in Projects">
     <td>@{{ Project.id }}</td>
     <td>@{{ Project.thumb }}</td>
     <td>@{{ Project.name }}</td>
     <td>@{{ Project.active }}</td>
     <td>@{{ Project.created_at }}</td>
</tr>
```

**Error:**

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$created_at

**I tried also:**

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
     return [
          'created' => $project->created_at->diffForHumans()
     ];
}
```

and it displays what I was looking for but it only show just one data.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not to format the `create_at` itself, but instead create a copy of it inside your model, and use it anytime you want.

So within your `User.php` model:

```
protected $appends = ['created_date'];
```

Create an attribute mutator:

```
public function getCreatedDateAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

Sample Output

```
10 seconds ago
```

Answer (score 1):

You write direct in blade to get human readable format.

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($Project.created_at))->diffForHumans()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution that you can use anywhere with casting attribute. Check Code below

```
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class CreateAtCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Transform the attribute from the underlying model values.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        $date = Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
        return $date;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the attribute to its underlying model values.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return array
     */
    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

in Modal

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Casts\CreateAtCast;

class Project extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at'        => CreateAtCast::class,
    ];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

then direct use project.create_at